# How to Implement Moneris Fraud Prevention Tools on our Magento site?

Tags: customer-address

I do not know where to look to enable fraud prevention tools on our magento site. I'd like to enable name and address lookup and everything else available except 'verified by visa'. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go to SiftScience, first 10,000 transactions per month are free, they have a Magento extension, it's developed by ex Google Engineers, and used by Fortune companies.